# ImportError: No module named roslib

Tags: ros, roslib

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am having a problem running python files. Here are the 1st-3rd lines of the py file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import roslib; roslib.load_manifest('irobot_mudd')
import rospy
```

Whenever I run $ sudo python ml.py (ml.py being the python file in question)- as well as any other py file importing roslib, I get the error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ml.py", line 2, in <module>
    import roslib; roslib.load_manifest('irobot_mudd')
ImportError: No module named roslib
```

If I run

```
$ python ml.py
```

I get the following back:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ml.py", line 4, in <module>
    import cv_bridge
ImportError: No module named cv_bridge
```

My setup.sh file is as follows:

```
export ROS_ROOT=/opt/ros/electric/ros
export PATH=${ROS_ROOT}/bin:${PATH}
export PYTHONPATH=${ROS_ROOT}/core/roslib/src:${PYTHONPATH}
export ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=/opt/ros/electric/stacks 
if [ ! "$ROS_MASTER_URI" ] ; then export ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311 ; fi
```

this is what my python path looks like:

```
echo $PYTHONPATH 
/opt/ros/electric/ros/core/roslib/src:/opt/ros/electric/ros/core/roslib/src:/opt/ros/electric/ros/core/roslib/src:/opt/ros/electric/ros/core/roslib/src:/opt/ros/electric/ros/core/roslib/src:/opt/ros/electric/ros/core/roslib/src:/opt/ros/electric/ros/core/roslib/src:/opt/ros/electric/ros/core/roslib/src:/opt/ros/electric/ros/core/roslib/src:/opt/ros/electric/ros/core/roslib/src:/opt/ros/electric/ros/core/roslib/src:/opt/ros/electric/ros/core/roslib/src:/opt/ros/electric/ros/core/roslib/src:/opt/ros/electric/ros/core/roslib/src:/opt/ros/electric/ros/core/roslib/src:/opt/ros/electric/ros/core/roslib/src:
```

Here is the result of ls /opt/ros/electric/ros/core/roslib/src:

```
package.cpp  ros  roslib
```

And the result of ls /opt/ros/electric/ros/core/roslib/src/roslib/*.py is:

```
/opt/ros/electric/ros/core/roslib/src/roslib/exceptions.py   /opt/ros/electric/ros/core/roslib/src/roslib/params.py
/opt/ros/electric/ros/core/roslib/src/roslib/genpy.py        /opt/ros/electric/ros/core/roslib/src/roslib/resources.py
/opt/ros/electric/ros/core/roslib/src/roslib/gentools.py     /opt/ros/electric/ros/core/roslib/src/roslib/rosenv.py
/opt/ros/electric/ros/core/roslib/src/roslib/__init__.py     /opt/ros/electric/ros/core/roslib/src/roslib/roslogging.py
/opt/ros/electric/ros/core/roslib/src/roslib/launcher.py     /opt/ros/electric/ros/core/roslib/src/roslib/rospack.py
/opt/ros/electric/ros/core/roslib/src/roslib/manifestlib.py  /opt/ros/electric/ros/core/roslib/src/roslib/rostime.py
/opt/ros/electric/ros/core/roslib/src/roslib/manifest.py     /opt/ros/electric/ros/core/roslib/src/roslib/scriptutil.py
/opt/ros/electric/ros/core/roslib/src/roslib/message.py      /opt/ros/electric/ros/core/roslib/src/roslib/srvs.py
/opt/ros/electric/ros/core/roslib/src/roslib/msgs.py         /opt/ros/electric/ros/core/roslib/src/roslib/stack_manifest.py
/opt/ros/electric/ros/core/roslib/src/roslib/names.py        /opt/ros/electric/ros/core/roslib/src/roslib/stacks.py
/opt/ros/electric/ros/core/roslib/src/roslib/network.py      /opt/ros/electric/ros/core/roslib/src/roslib/substitution_args.py
/opt/ros/electric/ros/core/roslib/src/roslib/os_detect.py    /opt/ros/electric/ros/core/roslib/src/roslib/xmlrpc.py
/opt/ros/electric/ros/core/roslib/src/roslib/packages.py

import sys; sys.path
['/home/machira/ros_workspace/irobot_mudd', '/usr/bin', '/usr/lib/python2.7', '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PIL', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gst-0.10', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk-2.0', '/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntu-sso-client', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntuone-client', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntuone-control-panel', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntuone-couch', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntuone-installer', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntuone-storage-protocol', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/wx-2.8-gtk2-unicode']
```

Running  $ cd /opt/ros/electric/ros/core/roslib/src;python -c 'import roslib; print "success"' results in;

```
success
user@user-K53SV:/opt/ros/electric/ros/core/roslib/src$
```

Any ideas on what is wrong? Also why the PYTHONPATH looks as it does? Should it?

Thanks!

raymachira

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/41241/importerror:-no-module-named-roslib/) by [raymachira](https://answers.ros.org/users/3013/raymachira/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2012-08-13

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [raymachira](https://answers.ros.org/users/3013/raymachira/) on 2012-08-13**:
I have tried sourcing /opt/ros/electric/setup.sh While this command works, I still get the error

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2012-08-13**:
Please provide the complete backtrace. Maybe it contains something important.

**Comment by [raymachira](https://answers.ros.org/users/3013/raymachira/) on 2012-08-13**:
Backtrace of what exactly?

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2012-08-13**:
The python backtrace that shows you the import error. Please always copy-paste the exact error you are getting. See http://www.ros.org/wiki/Support

**Comment by [raymachira](https://answers.ros.org/users/3013/raymachira/) on 2012-08-13**:
Sure. Here it is: >>Traceback (most recent call last):

> > File "ros_workspace/irobot_mudd/ml.py", line 2, in 
> > import roslib; roslib.load_manifest('irobot_mudd')
> > ImportError: No module named roslib

**Comment by [raymachira](https://answers.ros.org/users/3013/raymachira/) on 2012-08-13**:
Sure. Here it is:

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2012-08-13**:
Could you please edit your original question and add it? That makes it way easier to read :)

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2012-08-13**:
Also, please execute `echo $PYTHONPATH` after you got the error, in the same terminal. Just to be sure your program uses the right path... :)

**Comment by [raymachira](https://answers.ros.org/users/3013/raymachira/) on 2012-08-13**:
Thanks Lorenz. I have added these changes. I hope they are helpful.

**Comment by [KruseT](https://answers.ros.org/users/888/kruset/) on 2012-08-13**:
The pythonpath should just be: /opt/ros/electric/ros/core/roslib/src, but having many of those does not hurt. Can you also execute ls /opt/ros/electric/ros/core/roslib/src and post the results in your question, please?

**Comment by [raymachira](https://answers.ros.org/users/3013/raymachira/) on 2012-08-13**:
Sure. I have done so KruseT

**Comment by [KruseT](https://answers.ros.org/users/888/kruset/) on 2012-08-13**:
This does not make much sense. Also post ls /opt/ros/electric/ros/core/roslib/src/roslib/*.py

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2012-08-13**:
Can you please not use cites but code blocks for code? Just copy-paste text, mark it and press Ctrl-k. That way, we don't lose any line breaks that might be important. Can you also post the output of the following entered in a python shell: import sys; sys.path

**Comment by [KruseT](https://answers.ros.org/users/888/kruset/) on 2012-08-13**:
The path  /opt/ros/electric/ros/core/roslib/src is missing from your sys.path. It should be in there if it was in your PYTHONPATH, unless what you do changes the PYTHONPAT or sys.path before you call import roslib.

**Comment by [raymachira](https://answers.ros.org/users/3013/raymachira/) on 2012-08-13**:
I called as you said I should, and the roslib directory exists. I still get the same error.

**Comment by [KruseT](https://answers.ros.org/users/888/kruset/) on 2012-08-13**:
Can you tell us more about what you do to get the error? Do you call a shell script, or a python script? What are the first line of the python script? What is the result of : $ cd /opt/ros/electric/ros/core/roslib/src;python -c 'import roslib; print "success"'

**Comment by [raymachira](https://answers.ros.org/users/3013/raymachira/) on 2012-08-14**:
I have added this information.

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2012-08-14**:
You seem to run the python file using sudo. That probably causes the problem. Run it without sudo.

**Comment by [raymachira](https://answers.ros.org/users/3013/raymachira/) on 2012-08-14**:
I have, I get a cv_bridge error now as above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You need to call:

```
source /opt/ros/electric/setup.sh
```

either manually or in your .bashrc.

Check whether /opt/ros/electric/ros/core/roslib/src exists, and if not, run

```
sudo aptitude reinstall ros-electric-ros
```

EDIT:
As Lorenz said, you should not use sudo. You should never ever ever use sudo, unless a tutorial tells you to.

So your only problem is:

```
import cv_bridge
ImportError: No module named cv_bridge
```

To import cv_bridge, cv_bridge must be listed in irobot_mudd/manifest.xml as

```
<depend package="cv_bridge"/>
```

Only then does roslib.load_manifest('irobot_mudd') put cv_bridge into the python path.

---

Originally posted by [KruseT](https://answers.ros.org/users/888/kruset/) with karma: 7848 on 2012-08-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 9